# Why am I getting error for this confusion matrix in R?

Tags: r, predict, confusion-matrix

I am using a binary value "Mpg01", where Mpg01 depicts if mileage is over median of data then 1 else 0:
 I have run a logistic regression however when creating a confusion matrix: I am receiving the below error:

Input:

```
table(carslogic$Mpg01, predict > 0.5)

Output:
> table(carslogic$Mpg01, predict > 0.5)
Error in predict > 0.5 : 
  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

What is the reason for this error?How can i fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `class(predict)`?

Comment: 1            2            3            4            5 
2.538352e-04 8.159183e-05 3.818253e-04 3.887646e-04 3.531575e-04 
           6            7            8            9           10 
1.665192e-06 1.540124e-06 1.982014e-06 1.005454e-06 3.178014e-05 
          11           12           13           14           15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use predict() > 0.5
See this as example

```
data(mtcars)
fit <- glm((cyl>4) ~ mpg, data=mtcars )
table((mtcars$cyl>4), predict(fit)>0.5)

        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE     9    2
  TRUE      0   21
```